# How to prove that the infimum or supremum of a set does not exist by contradiction?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

While studying Karel Hrbacek's "Introduction to Set Theory," I began contemplating how to prove the existence of a supremum (or infimum) through a contradiction, given a partial order relation. Although the supremum and infimum are distinct concepts, they can be understood in a similar manner. For the sake of clarity, I will focus only on the method for proving the existence of a supremum.

Consider a partially ordered set (poset) denoted as $\langle A, \preceq \rangle$, where $\preceq$ represents a definable partial order relation on the set $A$. Let $B$ be a subset of $A$. We define $X \in A$ as the supremum of $B$ if it satisfies the following conditions:

**(1)** For every $Y \in B$, we have $Y \preceq X$. In other words, $X$ serves as an upper bound for $B$ in terms of $\preceq$.

**(2)** For any other upper bound $Z \in A$ of $B$, we have $X \preceq Z$.

To prove the existence of such a set $X$ by contradiction, we can assume that no such $X$ exists. This implies that for every $X \in A$, at least one (or both) of the following conditions holds:

**(1')** There exists $Y \in B$ such that $Y \npreceq X$.

**(2')** There exists an upper bound $Z \in A$ for $B$ such that $X \npreceq Z$.

To proceed with a proof by contradiction, we assume either or both of the conditions (1') and (2') and derive a contradiction using the definition of $\preceq$, any additional given premises, or logical reasoning.

I would like to know if this is the correct method for proving such existence by contradiction, so I would be very pleased if someone could check if everything is correct.